# Speed up filter and sum results based on multiple criteria?

Tags: google-sheets

I am filtering then summing transaction data based on a date range and if a column contains one of multiple possible values.

example data

```
    A      |  B  |                C                                  |   D
-----------|-----|---------------------------------------------------|-------
11/12/2017 | POS | 6443 09DEC17 C , ALDI 84 773 , OFFERTON GB        | -3.87
18/12/2017 | POS | 6443 16DEC17 C , CO-OP GROUP 108144, STOCKPORT GB | -6.24
02/01/2018 | POS | 6443 01JAN18 , AXA INSURANCE , 0330 024 1229 GB   | -220.10
```

I'm currently have the following formula, that works but is really quite slow.

```
=sum(
  iferror(
     filter(
         Transactions!$D:$D, 
         Transactions!$A:$A>=date(A2,B2,1),
         Transactions!$A:$A<=date(A2,B2,31),
         regexmatch(Transactions!$C:$C, "ALDI|LIDL|CO-OP GROUP 108144|SPAR|SAINSBURYS S|SAINSBURY'S S|TESCO STORES|MORRISON|MARKS AND SPENCER , HAZEL GROVE|HAZELDINES|ASDA")
     )
     ,0
  )
) * -1
```

The formula is on a seperate sheet that is just a simple view of the results breakdown for each month of a year

```
  |   A  | B  |     C
--|------|----|----------
1 | 2017 | 12 | <formula>  # December 2017
2 | 2017 | 11 | <formula>  # November 2017
3 | 2017 | 10 | <formula>  # October 2017
```

Is there a way to achieve this that would be more performant?

I tried using `ArrayFormula` and `SUMIF` which works for the string criteria but to add more criteria with `SUMIFS` for the date, it stops working.

I couldn't figure out a way to utilize `INDEX` and/or `MATCH`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=query(filter( {Transactions!$A:$A,
         Transactions!$D:$D},
         regexmatch(Transactions!$C:$C, "ALDI|LIDL|CO-OP GROUP 108144|SPAR|SAINSBURYS S|SAINSBURY'S S|TESCO STORES|MORRISON|MARKS AND SPENCER , HAZEL GROVE|HAZELDINES|ASDA")
     ), "select year(Col1), month(Col1)+1, -1*sum(Col2) group by year(Col1), month(Col1)+1", 0)
```

The result is a table like this:

```
year()  sum(month()1())    sum 
2017                 11    3.87
2017                 12    6.24
```

Add labels if needed. Sample query text with labels:

`"select year(Col1), month(Col1)+1, -1*sum(Col2) group by year(Col1), month(Col1)+1 label year(Col1) 'Year', month(Col1)+1 'Month'"`

The result:

```
Year   Month    sum 
2017      11    3.87
2017      12    6.24
```

**Explanations**

- the single formula report reduces the number of filter functions, so must work faster.
- Used query syntax. [more info here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage).

Comment: This wonderful does a lot of work of producing the output... one additional question, Is it possible to include empty months rows with a result of 0 instead at the moment it doesn't output anything?

Comment: To include empty months, you need to add them to the data. Create "dummy" months: `=query( {  {date(2018,1,1),0} ; {date(2018,2,1),0} ; ... filter(...) }, sql-text, 0)`